# How to use dictionaries .get method for counting?

Tags: python, dictionary

So I want to set up a function that takes a string and basically counts how many times a letter is repeating, and I want to do it with dictionaries. I've used an if else statement, but now I want to use the `.get` method. So far my code looks like this:

```
def histogram(s):
    d = dict()
    for c in s:
        d.get(c)
        d[c] = 1
    return d

g = histogram('bronto')
print(g)
```

This prints:

```
{'b': 1, 'r': 1, 'o': 1, 'n': 1, 't': 1}
```

However as you can see there should be 2 `o`'s. I cant do `d[c] += 1`, because it hasn't been previously declared. How do I get the function to count in the extra letters within that for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly what [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is for:

```
from collections import Counter
g = Counter('bronto')
```

However if you want to use plain `dict`s and `dict.get` you need to process the return value of `dict.get`, for example with:

```
d[c] = d.get(c, 0) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to check if the entry exists in the dictionary before trying to add to it. The simplest extension of what you've written so far is to check each character as you go.

```
def histogram(s):
    d = dict()
    for c in s:
        if c in d:
            d[c] += 1

        else:
            d[c] = 1

    return d

g = histogram('bronto')
print(g)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the `d[c] = d.get(c, 0) + 1`, and the `Counter` solutions, I'd like to point out the existence of `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def histogram(s):
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for c in s:
        d[c] += 1
    return d
```

`defaultdict` never raises a `KeyError`. It is initialized with a constructor (a class, or a function). If a key is missing, the constructor will be called without arguments and the returned value will be assigned to the key, before resuming the normal operation.

For this case I'd use `Counter`, but `defaultdict` can be useful in more general scenarios.